ggplot fill spilling over shape when used with different geoms
Im trying to confine the fill of b & c to their respective shapes.
The fill not being tied to a variable for the geom_bar is confusing but needs to be preserved for the final plot to work.
ggplot2 version is 3.3.6
library(tidyverse)

plot_data <- tibble(
  percentage_a = 40,
  percentage_b = 60,
  percentage_c = 80,
  label_b = "percentage b",
  label_c = "percentage c"
)

color_palette <- c(
  "#bdd7ee", # a
  "#4f81bd", # b
  "#254061" # c
)

ggplot(data = plot_data, aes(x = "1")) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = percentage_a, fill = "percentage a"), stat = "identity", width = 1.15) +
  geom_point(aes(y = percentage_b, fill = label_b), shape = 23, size = 10, position = position_nudge(x = -0.3)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = percentage_c, fill = label_c), shape = 21, size = 10, position = position_nudge(x = 0.3)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(size = 0.2,
                             title = "",
                             override.aes = list(shape = c(NA, 23, 21)
                             )
  )) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 100), expand = c(0.001, 0), labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_palette)

Here is a photoshoped picture of what the plot, specifically the legend, should look like:

Edit: The chosen answer works with ggplot 3.5.1 and above.

What should your expected plot look like?

Thanks for the remark, I added a picture to the op.

Setting fill = 'white' (or NA) for the legend.key element will remove the grey background from the shapes.
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = plot_data, aes(x = "1")) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = percentage_a, fill = "percentage a"), stat = "identity", width = 1.15) +
  geom_point(aes(y = percentage_b, fill = label_b), shape = 23, size = 10, position = position_nudge(x = -0.3)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = percentage_c, fill = label_c), shape = 21, size = 10, position = position_nudge(x = 0.3)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(size = 0.2,
                             title = "",
                             override.aes = list(shape = c(NA, 23, 21)
                             )
  )) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 100), expand = c(0.001, 0), labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_palette) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))



This feels like it should work, but does not for me. Which ggplot version are you using?

ggplot2 3.5.1

I tried it with ggplot2 3.5.1 and it works even without the theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white")) >___> Can you edit your answer to reflect that so i can upvote?

When I run the reprex from the question without updating the legend.key theme component I get the grey background behind the shapes in the legend.

You're right, my bad, ran your version on accident.
